# What is an overview of different denominations' beliefs about how Jesus Christ performed miracles? (By the Holy Spirit or by something else?)

Tags: life-of-jesus, christology, pneumatology, miracles

> for to one is given the word of wisdom through the Spirit, to another the word of knowledge through the same Spirit, to another faith by the same Spirit, to another gifts of healings by the same Spirit, to another the working of miracles, to another prophecy, to another discerning of spirits, to another different kinds of tongues, to another the interpretation of tongues. But one and the same Spirit works all these things, distributing to each one individually as He wills. ([1 Corinthians 12:8–11, NKJV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+12%3A8-11&version=NKJV))
>
> But in fact, it is best for you that I go away, because if I don’t, the Advocate won’t come. If I do go away, then I will send him to you. ([John 16:7, NLT](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2016:7&version=NLT))

My understanding is that miracles are performed in men by the work of the Holy Spirit. However, the Holy Spirit did not come to Earth until after Jesus left. Knowing this, what do different churches have to say on this issue? Did Jesus have the Holy Spirit anyway as a result of being fully God or did he do miracles by another means?  What is an overview of beliefs on this subject?

Comment: Historically, there is as least one other possibility: _And John bore witness, saying, "l saw the Spirit descending from heaven like a dove, and He remained upon Him."_ [John 1:32 NKJV]. May not be relevant to your question, but I'd hate to see the answer railroaded for a lack of options.

Comment: Remember to add (for example) the [tag:baptist] and [tag:methodist] tags if you're looking just for that perspective.  People subscribe to the tags and will often find your question more quickly if you do.

Comment: Baptist/Methodist isn't a good scope, they don't share much history and they aren't grouped together now much that I'm aware.

Comment: @curiousdannii I am a nondenominational Protestant, but I'm forced to choose a denomination by the rules of the site, so I chose those two because those are the Protestant denominations I have most commonly seen here.

Comment: You'd probably prefer to ask [overview questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/870/6071) then.

Comment: This is now an overview question. Thanks.

Comment: @Hylian I've made it more clear that you are asking for an overview.  Another option, which might be more useful to you, would be to ask for an overview of Protestant beliefs, so as to exclude traditions less similar to Baptists and Methodists.  That would probably also make it easier to answer.  But it's up to you.

Comment: @Nathaniel Thanks. I'll go ahead and leave it as is, as I don't believe something as specific as this would have too much room for drastically conflicting interpretations.

Comment: *However, the Holy Spirit did not come to Earth until after Jesus left*  Can you support that assertion?  It appears to conflict  with the belief in the Triune God.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I gave the verse in the question. I don't see how that conflicts, either.

Comment: You are making an assumption, that because Jesus would send the Holly Spirit (as promised) that the Holy Spirit had never been present before. I do not find your scriptural references in support of that assumption.  FWIW.  You assume If P Then Not Q, but that assumption is unsupported.

Comment: The Holy Spirit wouldn't need to "come" if it had already been there. It would be entirely unnecessary for the Holy Spirit to be sent if it had already been there. Pentecost would be a demonstration of the Holy Spirit being sent. Anyway, the burden of proof would be to demonstrate that the Holy Spirit HAD been present instead of that it had not.

Answer (score 0):

One theory that suggests the source of the miracles was from other the Holy Spirit is  [Dr. Cleon Skousen's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Cleon_Skousen) "Intelligence Theory"(summarized [here](https://lehislibrary.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/cleon-skousens-intelligence-theory-of-atonement/), transcript [here](https://rcronk.wordpress.com/2007/07/27/a-personal-search-for-the-meaning-of-the-atonement/)), which he explained in a talk to a group of LDS missionaries.

It's not official LDS doctrine, but it is based primarily on LDS scripture. The gist of it is this:

1. Before the creation, everything was organized into intelligences.
2. God is the greatest of these intelligences.
3. Upon creation, intelligences were assigned to the elements. Some intelligences just know how to rotate in circles around protons and neutrons, some intelligences were assigned to animals, or humans. Clearly based on their capacity and purpose.
4. God's power is his honor. These intelligences obey God because He is perfect in every sense. The elements change at His requests in order to pay Him this honor.

There are apparently some [arguments](http://emp.byui.edu/marrottr/Skousen-Williams.pdf) (which I have not yet read), and my quick summary probably doesn't do the theory justice, but it is one (I'm sure of many) theories that may be able to answer your question.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this answer addresses the OP's question about how Jesus performed miracles.

Comment: Hey @bradimus, I must be missing something, then. Talk it out with me. The OP is asking for different views on how Jesus performed miracles, whether by the Holy Spirit or something else. My answer suggests "something else". Let me update the answer to explicitly stated that.

Comment: Or does the overview from each denomination need to be all one answer rather than multiple answers... Cause I couldn't provide that answer...

Comment: 1. So, you're saying that Jesus commanded intelligences on Earth as God did in heaven? 2. @rhamilton An overview question does require each denomination in one answer, but I would be satisfied with just two denominations.